# docker-py set network mode to host

Tags: python-2.7, docker, docker-compose, dockerpy

I have docker `Docker version 1.10.3, build 20f81dd` and a client `docker-py==1.9.0`. I want to be able to set `--net=host` (docker) or `net: host` (docker-compose) setting via python client, but the docs say `network_mode is available since v1.11`.

How can I emulate this behaviour via python client?

Answer (score 0):

I see in the docs

https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#container-objects

among other things

`host  - > Use the host network stack.`

Answer (score 0):

I Used something like this in my code.

```
container = client.containers.run("<imagename>", name = "sample", network_mode = "host")
```